# Confirm button greyed out on Metamask when trying to interact with Uniswap contract

Tags: contract-development, metamask, ethers.js, uniswap, ethereumjs

I'm trying to run a script in order to execute a Uniswap swap. When the transaction is submitted, MetaMask doesn't allow me to confirm the transaction (the confirm button is greyed out).
On MetaMask's website it [says](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360044703372-How-to-fix-insufficient-funds-error-or-greyed-out-confirm-button#:%7E:text=Why%20is%20my%20%22Confirm%22%20button,to%20pay%20for%20the%20transaction.) that the reason for this greyed out confirm button is insufficient funds, however, I have more than enough ETH to cover the transaction + gas fees.

The script looks as follows:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import uniswapABI from './uniswapABI.json';

const web3 = new Web3([Goerli Infura URL]);
// const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
const uniswapContract = new web3.eth.Contract(uniswapABI, '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D');

const fromToken = '0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6'; // WETH
const toToken = '0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984'; // UNI
const amountIn = web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether');
const amountOutMin = web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether');
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 3; // 3 minutes from now

if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('MetaMask is installed!');
}

ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

async function executeExactSwap() {
    console.log("executeExactSwap");
    const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

    console.log("accounts", accounts);

    const account = accounts[0];

    console.log("account", account);

    const uniswapData = uniswapContract.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        [fromToken, toToken],
        account,
        deadline
    ).encodeABI();


    const transactionParameters = {
        nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
        value: '0x00', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account.
        chainId: '0x5', // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
        from: account,
        to: uniswapContract.options.address,
        data: uniswapData,
        gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation
        gas: '0x2710', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation
        value: '0x00', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account
    };

    console.log("eth_sendTransaction");

    const txHash = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
        params: [transactionParameters],
    });

    console.log("sendTransaction complete", txHash);
}


console.log("function call");
executeExactSwap();
```

Comment: Did you approve the uniswap contract to access the tokens?